# Objective c,Get MailCore CTCoreMessage attachments

Tags: attachment, mailcore

I'm trying to get the attachments of a Mail with MailCore but it's always empty. My code is

```
    [myAccount connectToServer:@"imap_server" port:143 connectionType:CONNECTION_TYPE_PLAIN authType:IMAP_AUTH_TYPE_PLAIN login:@"username" password:@"password"];
    CTCoreFolder *inbox = [myAccount folderWithPath:@"INBOX"];
    NSSet *messageSet = [inbox messageObjectsFromIndex:1 toIndex:0];
    NSEnumerator *objEnum = [messageSet objectEnumerator];
    id msg;

    while(msg = [objEnum nextObject]) {
        [msg fetchBody];
        NSArray *atts=[msg attachements];
        //Do something with  atts
    }
```

but the atts is always empty!Somebody please tell me why??I am sure there are two attachments in the newst mail message,and I can even get some infomation through [msg render] method,but it is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to call fetchBody or fetchBodyStructure on the message. something like:

```
[msg fetchBody];
```